# Gstreamer rtspsrc+decodebin vs uridecodebin

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

Consider the following gstreamer commands (I'm trying them in Windows):

1. ```
   gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://<path-to-stream> ! decodebin ! autovideosink
   ```
2. ```
   gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://<path-to-stream> ! autovideosink
   ```

Both commands should play video on auto created window. But in my case first one can start playing only about in 1 of 5 attempts. Whereas second one works every time.

In case of failure first command prints out the following messages:

> ```
> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
> Progress: (open) Opening Stream
> Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://<path-to-stream-here>
> Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
> Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
> Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
> Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
> Progress: (open) Opened Stream
> Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
> New clock: GstSystemClock
> Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
> Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
> Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
> WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0: Delayed linking failed.
> Additional debug info:
> ./grammar.y(506): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
> failed delayed linking some pad of GstDecodeBin named decodebin0 to some pad of 
> GstAutoVideoSink named autovideosink0
> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
> Additional debug info:
> gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtsp
> src0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
> streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
> Execution ended after 0:00:02.289918784
> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Setting pipeline to READY ...
> Setting pipeline to NULL ...
> Freeing pipeline ...
> ```

What's the main difference between those commands from user's point of view?
Is it possible to make first command more reliable (i.e. works without errors like second one)?

Answer (score 0):

Has you set other properoties, such as `caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264"`.
If the parameters don't match, it will report an error!